# Connecting to named instance of Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to connect Excel to Microsoft SQL Server, the problem is there are two named instances of server.

- default instance (localhost)
- `SRV1` instance

when I connect using `COMPUTER_NAME` or IP address, I get connected to the default instance, but I need to connect to `SRV1`.

I tried `COMPUTER_NAME/SRV1` and `IP_ADDRESS/SRV1`, both did not work. I need help thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COMPUTER_NAME\SRV1` syntax will give you what you need, but only if the SQL Browser service is running on that box. If not, you will need to know the port which the named instance is configured to listen on, and specify the server name in the `ipaddr,port_number` format (yes, the separator is a comma, not a colon).

Comment: Adding the port number worked for me!
Thank you very much sir! You saved me.